# How to permanently save controller input settings on higan emulator?

Tags: games, gamepad, emulation, administrator, ubuntu-emulator

How to permanently save controller input settings on higan? The controller of choice is a Xbox 360 controller, the settings are set and work just fine, until I close the higan emulator. When opening the emulator back up the controller settings have reset. On Windows this problem could be easily fix by running the higan emulator as an administrator. This would give the program/apt permission to edit and save registry settings for future references. The question could also be... how do I run higan as an administrator on Ubuntu? BUT I'm new to Ubuntu, and I'm not quite sure how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need root privileges to save settings of higan.
The configuration file (settings.bml) should be located in the folder `~/.config/higan` (this is the same as `/home/<username>/.config/higan`).
Check the permissions of this folder if higan is not able to save its settings.
You should be the owner of the folder and the file(s) in it.